# Upgrade Hyperledger 1.4 to 2.2 brings errors

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to move everything to 2.2 version using same chaincode but getting an error while installing channel 'transactcc':

```
Error: error getting chaincode deployment spec for transactcc: 'go list' failed with: package transactcc is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/transactcc): exit status 1
```

Please advise.
Also will appreciate a lot for a migrate 1.4 to 2.2 doc\any experience shared.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The fix was for a changes in GO mod, following command fixed the issue:

```
go env -w GO111MODULE=off
```